Story identification: DeviantArt webcomic (around 2010) in a futuristic dystopia with a crazy protagonist
I'm looking for this webcomic I used to follow in DeviantArt around 2008-2012. It's a webcomic, done in the digital speed painting style that was so popular back then.
It's set in a futuristic dystopia where there are drones and bots all over the metropolis. All the main cast (I think they were loosely a Power Trio) are wearing gas masks and heavy winter clothing. They are subversives in their own way, running into the drones and bots, and actually, I think, outright wanted by law.
The main character, however, is this crazy unpredictable guy. He goes by a generic, if grandiose, name; something like "The Major", "The Captain", "The General", etc. I think it was implied that the adventures he is having in this persona are just figments of a wild dream of another guy in some sort of facility somewhere, plugged-in, Matrix style.
My strongest memory of this comic is this encounter the MC had with a drone. The drone identifies him as a fugitive and begins the process of arrest. MC pours a cup of coffee on the drone, causing the drone to malfunction. He then proceeds to ride the newly-reprogrammed drone to escape.
I am most interested in the coffee-cup scene I described above. I'll know it when I see it. Even if you can just link me to that frame in the comic, I'll take that.

Romantically Apocalyptic by Vitaly S Alexius


The nuclear Apocalypse has come and gone, scarring the cityscape into an almost unrecognizable scene of twisted metal. Dangerous mutant animals prowl the dark recesses of the underground tunnels. Aliens pop up every once in a while to steal one of the few surviving members of the human race.
So life is a constant battle just to stay alive, right?
Actually it's really, REALLY boring. Aliens and monsters are few and far between, so mostly you just have the barren wasteland, its long dead skeletal occupants, whatever you manage to find, plus your imagination to keep you entertained.
Romantically Apocalyptic is dark comedy webcomic written by Vitalty S. Alexius. It follows an enigmatic survivor named Zee Captain and his/her team: Pilot, Sniper (a.k.a. "Mr. Snippy"), and (later on in the webcomic) Engineer (a.k.a. "Engie"), as they attempt to stay alive in this dangerous environment. But mostly? They're going to try to keep themselves from succumbing to boredom. Originally written in comic format, the series has undergone a soft reboot as a graphic web novel while occasionally incorporating several of the old comics.

The TV Tropes entry mentions that the situation of it all being a dream/hallucination was teased, and kind of resolved, but maybe not entirely (I suspect that #121 refers to the old webcomic, as Chapter 121 doesn't seem to describe this).

All Just a Dream: Sniper has this feeling. Turns out it just an evil entity that's manipulating his thoughts. Or is it? See Schrödinger's Butterfly.

All of the mind-screwy stuff seems to actually have been a dream, or at least the entity messing with his mind as of #121


This might be in reference to his encounter with the Arbitrator.

Shortly after that, The Sniper was kidnapped by an alien judge and confined in the spaceship of the Arbitrator. It tried to convince the captured sniper, that the Captain is only another personality of The Sniper. The Sniper also opened his backpack and recovered Captain's mask, hat, goggles and scarf. This evidence threw The Sniper into a deep identity crisis. Although in the aftermath of the Ancestors Story Arc, it is shown that the Captain is not another personality, but instead placed his/her facial wear into the Sniper's backpack.

Captain's wiki entry mentions the recurring joke of him disabling opponents with the contents of zer mug.

The Captain's primary weapon, if it can be called that, is the mug, filled with scalding to scorching hot coffee, tea or water. Captian has at least once used its incredibly hazardous contents to disable an alien robot.

Found with a search for tvtropes webcomic gas mask which brought up Gone With The Blastwave, which mentioned Romantically Apocalyptic for a comparison, and the name struck me as familiar.

The good news is that it's apparently still updating on Royal road. The bad news is that early scenes are apparently being redrawn, so you can only find the original work if you buy the physical books, which no longer seem to be being sold.

Oh my god it is! I've been googling for "deviantart webcomic the captain/general/major" and it was "Zee Captain" all along. No wonder I wasn't getting even close.
